# Set display option by getting working area uses in a .bat

Tags: windows, command-line, display, batch-file, automation

I'd like to make a simple .bat to set the right display option depending of screen usage. Can you help me out?

I don't see what's not working with what I've done so far, but I only have little experience with cmd...

```
#retrive virtual Screen with to compare to working area
set VSW= [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::VirtualScreen.Width
set WAW = [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::WorkingArea.width

#comparing and chose diplay option
if %WAW% leq %VSW% (
displayswitch.exe /clone
) else
displayswitch.exe /extend
```

Comment: The short answer is you mixed powershell code at the top, with batch file code at the bottom. Pick which you intend to use. I recommend powershell.

Comment: Thank's Appleddity, (can't answer in comments). I can't find how to translate in PowerShell... I don't find display control in official documentation either in any forum post using a search engine.

Comment: `#` is not the begin for comments in batch, and don't leave spaces around variables like `VSW= ...`. And comparing strings like that won't work

Comment: Welcome to Super User! It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

To have a syntactically correct powershell script:

```
#retrive virtual Screen with to compare to working area
Add-Type -Assembly System.Windows.Forms
$VSW = [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::VirtualScreen.Width
$WAW = [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::WorkingArea.width

#comparing and chose diplay option
if (%WAW% -le %VSW%){
    displayswitch.exe /clone
) else {
    displayswitch.exe /extend
}
```

But it won't (well) work for example in dual monitor systems or with a sidebar.